# Lua use a variable in an object reference?

Tags: lua

Is it possible to use a variable in an object reference in Lua? For example, a.Value is a string, and a.Value = "b". I would like to access a.b.c.d, or a.(a.Value).c.d. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax `a.b` is actually shorthand for `a["b"]`. To do what you want, you'd get rid of the `"b"` and instead use the variable, like this:

```
a[a.Value].c.d
```

Comment: Interesting! So objects can be treated like arrays (if I'm not confusing my array syntax)? Seems to work! Thank you!